# How to Specify Columntype in fluent nHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class `CaptionItem`

```
public class CaptionItem
    {
        public virtual int SystemId { get; set; }
        public virtual int Version { get; set; }        
        protected internal virtual IDictionary<string, string> CaptionValues {get; private set;}
}
```

I am using following code for nHibernate mapping

```
Id(x => x.SystemId);
            Version(x => x.Version);
            Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
            HasMany(x => x.CaptionValues)
                .KeyColumn("CaptionItem_Id")
                .AsMap<string>(idx => idx.Column("CaptionSet_Name"), elem => elem.Column("Text"))
                .Not.LazyLoad()
                .Cascade.Delete()
                .Table("CaptionValue")
                .Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
```

So in database two tables get created. One `CaptionValue` and other `CaptionItem`. In `CaptionItem` table has three columns

```
1. CaptionItem_Id     int
2. Text               nvarchar(255)
3. CaptionSet_Name    nvarchar(255)
```

Now, my question is how can I make the columnt type of `Text` to `nvarchar(max)`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many things, but nothing was solving the problem. Eventually I solved it. I just changed a bit in the mapping code. The new mapping code is given below

```
Id(x => x.SystemId);
            Version(x => x.Version);
            Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
            HasMany(x => x.CaptionValues)
                .KeyColumn("CaptionItem_Id")
                .AsMap<string>(idx => idx.Column("CaptionSet_Name"), elem => elem.Columns.Add("Text", c => c.Length(10000)))
                .Not.LazyLoad()
                .Cascade.Delete()
                .Table("CaptionValue")
                .Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
```

So I just added `c => c.Length(10000)`. Now, in the database the columntype of `Text` will be `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Hope it will help anybody else.

Comment: Every length that is > 4000 transformed to (MAX)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, using the following:

```
Id(x => x.Text).CustomSqlType("nvarchar(max)"); 

// For older versions of Fluent NHibernate   
Id(x => x.Text).CustomSqlTypeIs("nvarchar(max)");
```

**Edit:**

Bipul, Why not create a mapping for the `CaptionValues` and in that mapping, specify that, the type of `Text` is nvarchar(max) ?

Comment: Hey Mahesh, thanks for your reply. I knew we can set the column type using CustomSqlType(). But here situation is different. I was not able to use CustomSqlType() with HasMany() and AsMap(). Therefore I was looking for any alternative.

Comment: @Bipul: Edited answer with a suggestion