# Fluent NHibernate automap list of strings with nvarchar(max)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent NHibernate 1.2 for NHibernate 3.1. I have a class:

```
public class Marks
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<string> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

In the mapping for the Marks class, I have:

```
HasMany(m => m.Answers).Element("Value");
```

When the tables are created, an "Answers" table get created with the following columns:

```
Marks_id (FK, int, not null)
Value (nvarchar(255), null)
```

What I would like to do is have the Value be nvarchar(max). I'd prefer not doing this for every string in every class, just for this one class.

I have looked at these posts: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690775/how-do-you-automap-listfloat-or-float-with-fluent-nhibernate), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606607/mapping-collection-of-strings-with-nhibernate), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645024/how-to-specify-columntype-in-fluent-nhibernate), but haven't found anything yet that helps.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer. If you need additional information, please let me know.

**Edit:**
This is the code that resolves the issue:

```
HasMany(x => x.Answers).Element("Value", x => x.Columns.Single().Length = 4001);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force mapping `string` to longer column at each column level in mapping either by using `CustomSqlType("nvarchar(max)")` or, bit more universally, by setting `Length(4001)` (SQL Server magic number, above which it creates `nvarchar(max)` automatically).

To apply it automatically for all `string` columns in your entities, you can write your own [FluentNHibernate convention](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions):

```
public class LongStringConvention : IPropertyConvention, IPropertyConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Type == typeof(string));
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Length(4001);
    }
}
```

And register it in mapping container i.e. like that:

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Mappings(...)
    .Conventions.Add<LongStringConvention>()
```

To apply it for collection of strings, you can use custom element mappings:

```
HasMany(x => x.Answers).Element("Value", x => x.Columns.Single().Length = 4001);
```

Comment: Neither of those worked. If I set Map(m => m.Answers).CustomSqlType("nvarchar (max)"), I receive the error "Could not determine type for: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1". And even though I don't want to do the universal option, I tried it and the columns still remain at the default 255 length.

Comment: Ah, I've missed that you have collection of strings. Try `HasMany(m => m.Answers).Element("Value", e => e.Length(4001))`

Comment: I really appreciate your help so far. That didn't work either. I don't know if it will help or not, but if I look at the hbm.xml file that gets generated, there is a length on the element that I wasn't seeing before, it just isn't applying to the column.  `<element type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" length="4001"> <column name="Value"/> </element>`

Comment: OK, it suprised me a bit, but I figured it out. Use this: `HasMany(x => x.Answers).Element("Value", x => x.Columns.Single().Length = 4001);`

Comment: That's it!!! I've been trying to get this to work for days. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @NOtherDev this doesn't seem to work in the newer version of nhibernate. I keep getting: "Error Property or indexer 'FluentNHibernate.MappingModel.ColumnMapping.Length' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue myself and the above answers were most helpful in pointing me in the right direction...but I'm using a slightly newer version of FluentNH.

For Fluent NHibernate 1.3 and NH 3.3.1, the correct code is:

```
HasMany(x => x.Answers).Element("Value", x => x.Length(4001));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above only work for older version of nhibernate.
If you try `HasMany(x => x.Answers).Element("Value", x => x.Length(4001));` you will get the following:

> Error Property or indexer
>   'FluentNHibernate.MappingModel.ColumnMapping.Length' cannot be
>   assigned to -- it is read only

The **correct** way to do this now is (NHibernate 4.0.2.4, FluentNHibernate 2.0.1.0):

```
HasMany(m => m.Answers).Element("Value", e => e.Length(4001))
```